# Foreward email from postfix to java application

Tags: java, perl, postfix-mta

In our current implementation we are forewarding all relevant emails to a mail alias that triggers a perl script, which is processing the email. In /etc/aliases we have something like:

```
emailuser | process_email.pl
```

When we replace the perl script by a java application, starting a java vn on every email is much more resource intensive than just starting up a perl interpreter.

```
emailuser | process_email.java
```

It would be better to pass the email to a runnig instance of the java application. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the java app open a named pipe and pipe the mail into it.

Comment: Ok, what about concurrent writes into the pipe?